# Ports for socket receiving and sending data in C

Tags: c, sockets, port

I've a question about how sockets works in C. English isn't my first language, but I'll do my best to explain my question.

My function should be able to **SEND** and **RECEIVE** data. The port for the outgoing data MUST be different from the one of incoming data.

For example, in this case **PORT1** can be the same of **PORT2**?

```
int ds_sock;
ds_sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
struct sockaddr_in my;
my.sin_family=AF_INET;
my.sin_port=           PORT1;
my.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
bind(ds_sock,&my,sizeof(my));

struct sockaddr_in Eaddr;
Eaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
Eaddr.sin_port=           PORT2;
Eaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=IP;
sendto(ds_sock,buff,1024,0,(struct sockaddr*)&Eaddr,sizeof(Eaddr));
```

Comment: What's the question? You can send to your own port, if that's what you need to do.

Comment: @EJP First of all thanks for your attention. I want to send the data to another client. My question is: the socked is "binded" with PORT1. Can it send out things through PORT2?
And also, PORT 1 can be the same of PORT2, or I'll receive any mistake because incoming port is the same of outgoing?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes.  The two ports could be the same.  Consider the following:

Computer A          Computer B

If A wants to send to B, A has to know what port B is listening on.
Later, if B wants to send to A, B has to know what port A is listening on.

It is possible that A is listening on port 7777; and that b is also listening on port 7777.
In that case, it is possible that (in your example) PORT1 could be the same as PORT2.

Another example...

If a web browser wishes to send a request to stackoverflow.com for a specific page, the request is sent to the well-known port 80 (stackoverflow.com:80), where the stackoverflow.com server is listening.  Then the stackoverflow.com server has to send a reply back to the web browser.  The question is, what port is the web browser listening on?
It is unlikely that the web browser is also listening on port 80.  Rather, it is listening on a port number that was dynamically assigned by the web browser's system.

When the web browser sent the request to the stackoverflow.com server, it informed the server of the socket it would be listening on in the IP "source" address.

So, to more directly answer your question;
  "Can PORT1 be the same as PORT2?"

Answer(s):

If the port is available on both systems, yes. 
   If the example is for a single system... no.  The second attempt to acquire
    the port (for listening) will fail (on the same system).

Comment: Thanks for your help. So.. what happens if A tries to send data through 7777 while B is sending data to A through 7777?
PS: could you confirm that the piece of code I wrote is right, both if I put PORT1=7777 and PORT2=7777 and also if i put PORT1=7777 and PORT2=6666?